# Bitcoin-Qt is shutting down my laptop

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am running Bitcoin-Qt, and it is shutting down my laptop while trying to synchronize. I even tried on a different laptop with the same result of shutting itself down.

This situation happens while synchronizing, the CPU usage and the CPU temperature raises dramatically and the computer doesn't have any other option than shutting itself down before becoming permanently damaged. How can I fix this problem?

Here are some of the system details:

[Samsung R730](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP-R730-JB02US) laptop with

- 4 GB RAM
- [Intel Core i3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i3_2) dual core processor
- [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit CPU (even per core) usage per process. Doing so would keep your CPU cycles low and wouldn't cause all that trouble to your computer.

The best way to do this is to set soft limits directly to your O/S, as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Realtime_process_management).

A freeware that also works is: [cpulimit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpulimit/files/cpulimit/cpulimit/), although I would strongly suggest you tune you real-time process management directly from your console, as described above.

Comment: You can also limit the number of CPU threads bitcoin uses for signature validation, using the -par=N command line option.

Comment: I managed to limit the temperature of the cores by using the following statement on my .xinitrc: `sudo cpupower frequency-set -g powersave`

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar happen on a cheapie vps, bitcoin-qt is a demanding program, it crashes for you because it's verifying all the transactions that ever happened with bitcoin. To lessen the load, just find a [torrent/download](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=117982.0) of the block chain. Also try out a thin-client (like electrum) if you only need basic wallet functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the cpu usage to increase, the client has a lot of work to do when synchronizing and verifying the block chain. The temperature should increase some but not dramatically, so you may have a cooling problem with your hardware. See if the same thing happens with other cpu intensive applications. If so, this is a hardware problem and nothing to do with Bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Multibit client. It doesn't download the blockchain, and is very fast.